# How can I initialize a 2d Array with no rows or columns, and create a function that takes user input, then updates the 2d array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, scanf

My real goal here is to initialize a 2d array, 
then call a function to get user input for the rows and columns, and then return the 2d array to main with the size that the user specifies.

Though I understand that it would be far more efficient to not use the GetData function to ask for user input, and instead put the input into the main function, my professor requires that I do.

This is the specific Prompt:

"GetData(): write a function that takes the reference of a 2D array, reference of variables, one for number of rows and another for number of columns as parameter.
In the function, it takes number of rows and number columns as user input and update the variable passed to it.
Then it takes the input for the matrix based on number of rows and columns."

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void GetData(int *rows, int *columns, int matrix[][*columns]);
    void Display(int rows, int columns, int matrix[][columns]);
    int main(void) 
    {
        int r1, c1, r2, c2;
        int m1[r1][c1];
        int m2[r2][c2];
        printf("Working for Matrix 1\n");
        GetData(&r1,&c1,m1);
        Display(r1,c1,m1);



        return 0;

    }

    void GetData(int *rows, int *columns, int matrix[][*columns])
    {
        // maybe instead of void it needs to return an integer pointer?
        int a, b, i, j,k;
        printf("Enter number of rows and columns: ");
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        *rows = a;
        *columns = b;
        printf("Enter data for %dx%d matrix",*rows,*columns);
        for(i = 0;i<*rows;i++)
        {
            printf("\nrow %d\n",i+1);
            for(j=0;j<*columns;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&k);
                matrix[i][j] = k;
            }
        }
    }

    void Display(int rows, int columns, int matrix[][columns])
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
                printf("%4d",matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

When this code is run, there is also a segmentation error, I am not too sure as of what that means or what is causing it.

Comment: regarding `int r1, c1, r2, c2;
        int m1[r1][c1];
        int m2[r2][c2];`  this results in undefined behavior because the variables: r1, r2, c1, c2 are not initialized before being used, so contain what ever garbage happened to be in memory where they are located on the stack.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. An array with no entries will never need updating. You need to go back to your bigger goal and think it through to come up with an implementable way of reaching it.

Comment: Have you considered getting the needed rows and columns before attempting to create the array?

Comment: @aviberger yes, I forgot to mention that this is an assignment. The assignment requires that I use a function to update the values for rows and columns.

Comment: To update or to obtain? If you are only doing this once, you only need to get the dimensions once and then there is never any reason to "update" them and you only need to create the array once. If you are doing this repeatedly for different dimensions, then it is a different design problem.

Comment: @aviberger I believe my professor wants me to update. It is for the sake of understanding pointers, not for efficiency sadly.

Comment: @Junehong Then I suspect this is also about working with dynamically allocated memory. Normal arrays are fixed size with size determined at compile time. The content can be updated as you wish at runtime, but not the size. Variable Length Arrays (VLAs), which you are trying to use in your code, have their size fixed when created at runtime. After, the content can be updated, but not the size. Pointers and dynamic memory (which you are not currently using) together can be used to emulate a 2 d array that can be resized at runtime. Have you discussed realloc() in class?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare: `int m1[r1][c1]`, `r1` and `c1` are *unitialized*. Thus, the compiler has no idea how large to make `m1`. Likewise for `m2`.

If you compiled with (e.g.) `-O2 -Wall`, the compiler would flag this for you.

You need something like:

```
int
main(void)
{

    int r1 = 10;
    int c1 = 12;
    int m1[r1][c1];

    int r2 = 5;
    int c2 = 7;
    int m2[r2][c2];

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

---

However, you prompt the user for the array dimensions in `GetData`, but that's too late in the process. I'd move that prompt into `main`:

```
int
main(void)
{
    int nrow;
    int ncol;

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &nrow, &ncol);

    int m1[nrow][ncol];
    int m2[nrow][ncol];

    ...

    return 0;
}
```